# Filter an array nested inside another array in a one liner

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to filter empty string entries in a series of nested arrays, but filter doesn't actually mutate the array.

```
const text = [
  ['222','','ghy','','hthb'],
  ['333','','ghw','','5gth'],
  ['444','','fht','','5gbh'],
]

text.map(el=>el.filter(entry => entry.trim() != ''))

console.log(text)
```

Comment: `filter` returns a new array, it doesn't modify the original.

Comment: `text = text.map(...`

Comment: If you want mutate the `text` array without creating a new one with `map`, use `forEach` like this: `text.forEach((el, i) => text[i] = el.filter(Boolean))`

Answer (score 5):

You could **assign** the mapped new arrays.

```js
var text = [['222', '', 'ghy', '', 'hthb'], ['333', '', 'ghw', '', '5gth'], ['444', '', 'fht', '', '5gbh']]

text = text.map(a => a.filter(Boolean));

console.log(text);
```

Comment: I want to keep them nested the order is important. I mean I want the text array to contain nested arrays I don't want to flatten it.

Comment: @S.Schenk They're still nested and the same order

Comment: An explanation as to why the OP's code did not work would improve this answer.

Comment: in your code, an assingment of the inner array is missing. this approach uses the filtered array with `map` and performes the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `map` and `filter` are not in-place operations, they return new arrays.

```js
let text = [
  ['222', '', 'ghy', '', 'hthb'],
  ['333', '', 'ghw', '', '5gth'],
  ['444', '', 'fht', '', '5gbh'],
]

text = text.map(el => el.filter(entry => entry.trim() != ''))

console.log(text)
```

Comment: `el = el.filter` doesn't do anything

Answer (score 2):

`map()` and `filter()` return new arrays, they don't modify the array in place.

If you want to modify the original top-level array in place, you can use `forEach()` and assign back to the array index.

Note that this still creates new nested arrays, there's no in-place version of `filter()` (although it would be easy to write it yourself using `splice()`).

```js
let text = [
  ['222', '', 'ghy', '', 'hthb'],
  ['333', '', 'ghw', '', '5gth'],
  ['444', '', 'fht', '', '5gbh'],
]

text.forEach((el, i) => text[i] = el.filter(entry => entry.trim()))

console.log(text)
```

You also don't need the test `!= ''`, as an empty string is falsey.